# Strange behavior related to /boot, grub.cfg and multiple drives

Tags: linux, boot, grub

First, I apologize if this has already been asked and answered; I was not able to find an existing answer.

I do have an x86/64 device that has two drives inside. I use dual boot for 2 linux systems.

The drives are setup like this:

```
-NVMe drive
  ├─/dev/nvme0n1p128
  ├─/dev/nvme0n1p1 (bootfs)
  └─/dev/nvme0n1p2 (rootfs)
-SSD drive
  ├─/dev/sda128
  ├─/dev/sda1 (bootfs)
  └─/dev/sda2 (rootfs)
```

UUIDs and PARTUUIDs are all different between drives and partitions.

bootfs on each drive is setup like this:

```
─boot
 ├─grub
 │ ├─boot.img
 │ ├─core.img
 │ └─grub.cfg
 └─vmlinuz
─efi
 └─boot
   └─bootx64.efi
```

Now, the strange behavior I encounter is this:
In the BIOS, when I select the NVMe drive as the startup drive, the grub.cfg file used **is the one in /dev/sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg**, but the vmlinuz used is the one from /dev/nvme0n1p1/boot/vmlinuz (as it should be).

In bold is the unexpected behavior. Why is the grub.cfg file read from the SSD drive that is not the selected boot drive in the BIOS, but the vmlinuz file read from the right drive (NVMe)?

If I select the SSD drive as the startup device in the BIOS, it is the same grub.cfg from /dev/sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg that is used (as I would expect here), and the vmlinuz from /dev/sda1/boot/vmlinuz (as I would expect as well here).

Is it normal? I would expect when the NVMe drive is selected as the boot drive to have the grub.cfg from /dev/nvme0n1p1/boot/grub/grub.cfg to be used, not the one from the SSD.

Thank you for your patience.

More details:

```
~# lsblk -f
 NAME          FSTYPE FSVER LABEL  UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
 sda                                                                                   
 ├─sda1        vfat                ABCD-1234                                           
 ├─sda2        ext4         rootfs ed0bc801-6679-4118-b8ad-28386c2e83d6                
 └─sda128                                                                              
 nvme0n1                                                                               
 ├─nvme0n1p1   vfat                5678-ABCD                                 5M    69% /boot
 ├─nvme0n1p2   ext4         rootfs ff313567-e9f1-5a5d-9895-3ba130b4a864    1.6G    20% /
 └─nvme0n1p128                                                                         
 ~# fdisk -x
 Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
 Disk model: NVME SSD 512GB                          
 Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
 Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
 I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
 Disklabel type: gpt
 Disk identifier: 4C2F5CD7-82D9-297C-31A4-0953C5B32A00
 First LBA: 34
 Last LBA: 1000215182
 Alternative LBA: 1000215215
 Partition entries LBA: 2
 Allocated partition entries: 128

 Device             Start        End   Sectors Type-UUID                            UUID                                 Name Attrs
/dev/nvme0n1p1       512      33279     32768 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4 4C2F5CD7-82D9-297C-31A4-0953C5B32A01      LegacyBIOSBootable
/dev/nvme0n1p2     33280    4227583   4194304 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4 4C2F5CD7-82D9-297C-31A4-0953C5B32A02      
/dev/nvme0n1p128      34        511       478 21686148-6449-6E6F-744E-656564454649 4C2F5CD7-82D9-297C-31A4-0953C5B32A80      

 Partition table entries are not in disk order.


 Disk /dev/sda: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
 Disk model: SPCC Solid State
 Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
 Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
 I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
 Disklabel type: gpt
 Disk identifier: B3D4E8E2-95E4-48A0-8530-93CEB6CB6D0C
 First LBA: 34
 Last LBA: 1000215182
 Alternative LBA: 1000215215
 Partition entries LBA: 2
 Allocated partition entries: 128

 Device        Start        End   Sectors Type-UUID                            UUID                                 Name Attrs
/dev/sda1       512      33279     32768 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4 001F6144-F22B-4119-AECF-E986C9EDF20E      LegacyBIOSBootable
/dev/sda2     33280    4227583   4194304 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4 C29A1F16-3054-47E2-A498-2AFAFDC6FFB2      
/dev/sda128      34        511       478 21686148-6449-6E6F-744E-656564454649 D400B1E5-FD8F-465E-8C40-87B39B7F5328      

 Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

And the grub.cfg file:

```
~# cat /boot/boot/grub/grub.cfg 
 serial --unit=0 --speed=115200 --word=8 --parity=no --stop=1 --rtscts=off
 terminal_input console serial; terminal_output console serial

 set default="0"
 set timeout="5"
 search -l kernel -s root

 menuentry "NVMe OpenWrt" {
    linux /boot/vmlinuz root=PARTUUID=4C2F5CD7-82D9-297C-31A4-0953C5B32A02 rootwait  console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8 noinitrd
}
 menuentry "NVMe OpenWrt (failsafe)" {
    linux /boot/vmlinuz failsafe=true root=PARTUUID=4C2F5CD7-82D9-297C-31A4-0953C5B32A02 rootwait  console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8 noinitrd
}
 menuentry "SSD OpenWrt" {
    linux /boot/vmlinuz root=PARTUUID=C29A1F16-3054-47E2-A498-2AFAFDC6FFB2 rootwait  console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8 noinitrd
}
 menuentry "SSD OpenWrt (failsafe)" {
    linux /boot/vmlinuz failsafe=true root=PARTUUID=C29A1F16-3054-47E2-A498-2AFAFDC6FFB2 rootwait  console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8 noinitrd
}
```

*Note: there are a /dev/sda3 and a /dev/nvme0n1p3 partitions, but they are irrelevant here as they have nothing to do with boot, system or rootfs, so I simplified the outputs.*

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252189/how-does-grub2-find-its-configuration-file-in-efi-boot/252190#252190

Comment: So grub pikup configuration from where it was during grub-install. So you may boot fom nvme and install grub on that nvme with new grub dir location

Comment: @gapsf : there was no grub-install (openwrt makes it all during compilation, and not much options there for grub). If I understand correctly, something in bootx64.efi or boot.img is hardcoded to look into /dev/sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg?

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved this by installing Ubuntu on a Docker container, compiling the latest Grub2 from within the container, then I used this configuration to be embedded in `bootx64.efi` making a file named `grub-buildin.cfg` with this inside:

```
search.fs_uuid 4C2F5CD7-82D9-297C-31A4-0953C5B32A01 root
set prefix=($root)/boot/grub
```

Then I used the grub-mkimage like this:

```
MODULES="configfile ext2 fat part_gpt normal linux ls boot echo reboot search search_fs_file search_fs_uuid search_label help font efi_gop efi_uga gfxterm"
./grub-mkimage -O x86_64-efi -o bootx64.efi -p /efi/boot -d ./grub-core search_fs_uuid -c ./grub-buildin.cfg $MODULES
```

This generated a `bootx64.efi` that I then put in */dev/nvme0n1p1*/efi/boot/ (replacing the old one). Then when I restarted, I had the menu from the **/dev/nvme0n1p1**/boot/grub/grug.cfg configuration file *(and not **/dev/sda1**/boot/grub/grug.cfg anymore)*, so all good as now, I have when I boot:

```
BIOS -> bootx64.efi on NVMe EFI -> GRUB config on NVMe EFI -> whatever I choose from menu.
```

Thank you @gapsf for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Normally where grub looks for grub.cfg is determined with `--boot-directory` of `grub-install`, and the default value is `/boot`, which means by default it depends on which partition is mounted on `/boot` when you run `grub-install`.

Comment: Thanks @Tom Yan, however, when installing OpenWrt, there is no grub-install nor much grub options in the configuration process (make menuconfig has only choice between EFI or legacy I believe). The way OpenWrt is installed the first time is through dd on the entire disk.